# What are alternatives uses for an espresso machine?

Tags: espresso-machine

Assuming that you have a real espresso machine, one that also does pre-infusion and has a steam wand, what are going to be alternative uses for it.

If you want you could also list things to be avoided, like those that would damage the machine or create hazards.

Comment: Optional such as what.

Answer (score 4):

- Sterilizing smaller items (pacifiers, bottle nipples, toothbrush
  heads, etc.)
- Loosening threaded bottle and jar lids for honey and other sticky substances
- Cleaning small items (watchbands, rings, bits of grunge around the pads for your eyeglasses)
- Toothpaste cap cleaning Quickly heating water for tea/chai
- Quickly heating water for shaving bowl
- Melting butter Blocking hats